# How to put image on button? wxwidgets c++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Hey guys I'm new in c++  wxwidgets programming.
I would like to know the easiest way to put an image into a button.
I tried :

```
button1 = new wxBitmapButton(side_panel, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap("image.png",wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG), wxPoint(150,30), wxSize(30, 30),wxBORDER_NONE);
```

[But I always get the same error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H3c3.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089747/wxwidgets-unable-to-load-images

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank you, but this doesn't help I don't have this kind of a problem

Comment: At least add the verbatim error text to the question, better yet a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.  With that little information answering will be pure guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the error dialog you see, you should see more information about the error, but my guess is that the image simply can't be found. You should check that the file `image.png` indeed exists in the current working directory of your program, i.e. the directory that you run it from, assuming you don't change it later.

You should also actually check for errors in your programs, even simple ones, i.e.

```
wxBitmap bmp("image.png");
if (!bmp.IsOk()) {
  ... handle the error somehow instead of blithely using an invalid bitmap ...
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, this means a lot to me.